# How to execute command from shell script on machineB and machineC by running it in machineA

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ubuntu

I have three machines as mentioned below -

```
machineA
machineB
machineC
```

machineB and machineC has this directory -

```
/bat/data/snapshot_t1/
```

Now I need to run my below shell script from machineA and figure out the latest directory in machineB and machineC (by logging into those machine I guess) under this path `/bat/data/snapshot_t1/`.

Below is my shell script in which I know how to get the latest directory using find command along with sort and tail.

Now I am supposed to run the below shell script from machineA and then find out the latest directory in machineB and machineC.. How to do that?

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly FILERS_LOCATION=(machineB machineC)
readonly DIRECTORY_LOCATION=/bat/data/snapshot_t1/

# login to machineB and find out the latest directory in machineB
dir1=`find $DIRECTORY_LOCATION -type d | sort | tail -1`; echo $dir

# login to machineC and find out the latest directory in machineC
dir2=`find $DIRECTORY_LOCATION -type d | sort | tail -1`; echo $dir
```

How do I login into machineB and machineC from the shell script which is running in machineA and then execute certain commands on machineB and machineC and get the result back and store it in some variable, let's say dir1 and dir2.

Suppose the login name is `david` and let's say I have the keys setup as well on machineB and machineC.

Comment: It's funny that your handle is `SSH`, because `ssh` is exactly the command you need to use...

Comment: @Floris. lol.. I also noticed that just now..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can copy `machineA`'s public key to `david@machineB` and `david@machineC`
search `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id`

After you setup the keys, you can run any command from `machineA` without manually keying in any password.
`ssh david@machineB hostname`

to get `dir1`.

`dir1=$(ssh david@machineB find $DIR -type d | sort | tail -1)`

Comment: @rulfeng: Thanks but how do I plugin this in my actual shell script. Let's say I have setup the proper keys in machineB and machineC.

Comment: I updated my answer, just replace `machineB` with `machineC`, you will get the value for `dir2`

Answer (score 2):

Use SSH to execute the command remotely and pipe the result into another program/shell script to process it. `ssh user@host yourscript.sh | anotherscript.sh`.

`ssh user@host yourscript.sh` executes your command on the remote machine and prints the result on `stdout`, so you can capture it and redirect it to a file (`ssh user@host yourscript.sh > result.txt`) to process later or directly pipe it into another script (`ssh user@host yourscript.sh | anotherscript.sh`).

You can check `$?` variable for the exit status of the remote command.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I was not able to understand clearly, can you provide a clear example? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Updated the answer with some explaining.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ssh

command is **ssh -p port_num user@host**

port_num is the **port number** by default it is **22**.
user is the **userName** 
host is the ip or **hostName**.